Why are 3 sibling kittens singling out and hissing at 1?
We took 4 sibling kittens to get fixed about 5 days ago. When they got back, 3 of them (2 girls/1 boy) started hissing at 1 (girl) whenever they accidentally got near her. They won’t play with her and they used to. She gets isolated. She tries to engage in play with them here and there but they just hiss at her and leave. She never hisses back just looks sad and confused.

How old are the cats? Was anything special done to the one isolated one? Like additional medication? Please click [edit] below your question and add the requested information directly to your question.

It isn't uncommon for a group of cats, coming back from the vet, to look at each other and say "this must be your fault, and besides, you still smell like the vet; ugh." Especially if they are still uncomfortable after a procedure. My pair did it for years.
I suspect it's partly because they would like to curse the human out, but that doesn't feel safe, so they grumble at each other instead.
I haven't dealt with larger groups, so I don't know whether the consensus on who to blame is common or not.
But as long as they get over it in a day or two, no harm done.
